# how to use Google API in meteor?

Tags: meteor, google-api

How can i access google api data in meteor. I created a google application with map api, contacts api and google+ api i have the api key, the client id, secret and user access token. I just want to access user's data using meteor Http.call() but it don't work. My error i get is "Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: ['email']
}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      alert("Đăng nhập thất bại")
    } else {
        HTTP.call("GET", "googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/109512668573472269428/people/visible?maxResults=100", function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
        })
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Please supply more information , error messages, and more complete code.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: have you set up API in google console.

Comment: yes i have a contacts api and a google+ api enable